# PHP SQL query, logicaly parse result

Tags: php, sql, boolean, logic

I am trying to generate a logical condition based on weather or not a value is in a table using the code below. The echoed result comes back as ["0"]. How do I parse that so php can interpret the value as a boolean?

```
$rowExists = mysql_query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE column_name = value)");

echo "result: ".json_encode(mysql_fetch_row($rowExists));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE column_name = value') or die(mysql_error());
$count  = mysql_result($result, 0, 0);

if ($count > 0) {
    echo 'It exists!';
}
```